# Struts2 + Spring3 + JUnit4 Integration

Tags: java, struts2, junit4, spring-3

I have tried to write unit test for Struts2 and Spring3 integration.
I have used struts2-junit plugin for jUnit4 test.
But the thing is action proxy returns null.

How can I solve it?

In the code below is my test class and other configuration. **Test class**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext.xml" })
public class StrutsTest extends StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase<MyAction> {
    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/myaction");
        MyAction myAction = (MyAction) proxy.getAction();
        request.setParameter("personBean.firstName", "Joe");
        request.setParameter("personBean.lastName", "Doe");
        String result = myAction.execute();
        assertEquals("Error", ActionSupport.SUCCESS, result);
    }
}
```

MyAction.java:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyAction implements Action  {
    private Person personBean;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("MyAction is called!");
        System.out.println("personBean.firstName"+personBean.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("personBean.firstName"+personBean.getFirstName());
        return ActionSupport.ERROR;
    }

}
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <!-- Constants -->
    <constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="applicationResources, actionErrorMapping, smsMessages" />
    <constant name="struts.codebehind.pathPrefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="2097152" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="myaction" class="com.struts.actions.MyAction">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com"  />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have included struts2-spring-plugin:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
       <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>STRUTS_VERSION</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. In web.xml try using

   ```
   <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   ```
3. In struts.xml try using

   ```
   <constant name="struts.objectFactory" 
             value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />
   ```

First tries crossing my mind... hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. They all are done already.The spring works fine. The thing is the ActionProxy returns null. I looked it up in debugging and it seems that my struts.xml configuration is read but doesn't produce my action. What can be wrong?

Comment: Are you using [`struts2-junit-plugin`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-junit-plugin) or [`struts2-junit4-plugin`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.struts2-conversation/struts2-junit4-plugin) ?

Comment: It's really strange... I tried in many ways by editing web.xml, applicationContext.xml, struts.xml etc... but in my test I always find the proxy :| Are you sure your folders are correctly packaged, the libraries are all of the same version, etc ?

Comment: I uploaded my project to Dropbox. You can check it out: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/chy0hp6at74fytx/VQ0eXKEUN6

Comment: Btw, web.xml is under WEB-INF folder and applicationContext.xml and struts.xml is under src/main/resources